# Is it possible to setup cordova for ios development in ubuntu?

Tags: ios, xcode, ubuntu, cordova

I am new in phonegap development. I have installed phonegap for android development in Ubuntu and able to make app for android devices. Now i want to build app for ios. I know for this i need xcode. I want to know is it possible to install xcode in ubuntu for ios development?

Answer (score 2):

No. To run Xcode you needs a Mac with a current version of OS X.